# How do i get the even digets from a number and multiple them eachother

Tags: c++

Please answer as fast as you can because I need it for an exam tomorrow, thanks!. I need the code if you don't mind write it on the awnser .

Comment: did you tried at least?

Comment: _"Please answer as fast as you can"_ Worst starting point here, you'll get downvoted as much it is possible. Stack Overflow isn't meant for short term  personal help!

Comment: *I need it for an exam tomorrow* -- So you know the question that will be asked on your exam before you take it?

Comment: Yes i tried for 5 days and it failed.

Comment: You won't get any code from here... You need to show effort and ask an specific question where you're stuck. Good luck with your tomorrow's test :) *I need the code if you don't mind* We also need your code and that you show some effort :)

Comment: @КостаЃорѓиевски Please stay off here, you're on the wrong site for your concerns.

Comment: If you have tried show us what you got

Comment: I get only the diggets but how can i make it to give me the even digets (do..while.)

Comment: @КостаЃорѓиевски _`cout << "Enter number" <<endl;`_  That's just ridiculoous. You'll probably fail your exam and that's good so. We don't need any more mediocre programmers spilling the field. no

Comment: Its an exam for a free couse , help me to start learning  it costs 100€ and i can get it free.

Comment: Pretend you're not writing a program.  You have a digit, say `8`.  How do you know it's even?  You have another digit, say `3`.  How do you know it isn't even?  What math formula, operation, etc. would you use to determine if a digit is even or not?  You need to answer that question first before writing any program.

Comment: @КостаЃорѓиевски And the fact that you didn't learn whole semester, and you are about to face the consequences, should concern us, why?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints to help you get started.

Isolating right most decimal digit:
`digit = number % 10;`

Shifting a decimal number right:
`number = number / 10;`

Testing a digit for even:
`bool is_even = (digit & 1) == 0;`

Exercises like this may be better processed using characters and strings rather than converting to a number.

Testing a character for even, in a string at position `i`:
`bool is_even = ((number_str[i] - '0') & 1) == 0;`